# Assigning a value to an dynamic array element results in subscript out of range error

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub ArrTest()
Dim Arr() As Variant

    Arr(1, 1) = "Test"

End Sub
```

I did not dimension the array as I do not know what size it will need to be.  I will eventually be writing this array to a spreadsheet.  I was attempting to assign the upper left hand corner of the cells that would be written in the future as "test".

Now if I understand correctly dynamic arrays start to index at 0, so the first element is really Arr(0,0).  I tried Arr(0,0) and got the same error.

I guess the real question is:

How to assign a value to an element of an undefined dynamic array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to dim the array to a size before you use it. This is pretty simple though:

```
Sub ArrTest()
    Dim Arr() As Variant

    redim Arr(0 to 1, 0 to 1)
    Arr(1, 1) = "Test"

    redim preserve Arr(0 to 2, 0 to 1)
    Arr(2, 1) = "Test2"

End Sub
```

The `redim` method will redimension your array. Using the keyword `Preserve` will insure that the data stored in the array is not lost during the redimensioning.

Comment: so if later on I have it stuck in the middle of a for X loop, I would have to redim the array each time.  And by the looks of it when you redim, you are just adjusting the upper index number to a new number.  so I could do `redim preserve Arr(0 to X, 0 to 1)`.

Comment: I assume you dropped the Arr by accident in the preserve example?

Comment: Yes on both counts. In a loop you would `redim preserve` each time. And I did accidently drop the `Arr` in the preserve statement.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use `ReDim Preserve Arr(LBound(Arr) to UBound(Arr) + 1, 0 to 1)` instead, to keep the code dynamic?

Comment: @Ralph I see where you are going with that Ralph. and I do like that option.  Since you are putting in a Lbound reference, does that mean you can have your index for your array elements start at some other number than 0?  can I have my first element at say Arr(3,4) if I needed it to be for some reason?

Comment: As far as I know you can only start at 1 or 0 using the `Option Base 0` or `Option Base 1` statement: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa266179(v=vs.60).aspx

Comment: `Ubound(arr)+` can be really handy if you have conditions in your for loop for sitcking the values in the array. This way you don't have to monkey with two variables (the loop's variable and the conditional counter). If you aren't conditionally adding items, then you can save some CPU by just going with the variable.

Comment: It may depend on the version of excel, but you can dim an array with any integer as the lbound. I've never felt the need to stray outside of the very standard and expected 0-based array though. If you are using the index for something more crafty, then it may be time to look into a more robust object like a Collection

Comment: @JNevill funny you should mention that as I am actually using two to 3 counters in my loops with conditions to keep track of things.  I am getting another error though on the redim.  I thought it was because I did not have some of my variables defined, but they are...

Comment: Not sure how to do this...should I edit the question or post a new question as to why  I am getting an error on redim when I redim with a variable for the new size of the array? ie ( `redim preserve Arr(0 to varX, 0 to varY)` with both varX and vary being defined as long and value of 2.

Comment: Probably best to go with a new question. You can reference this question in it if you think it would help.

Comment: @JNevill FYI.  Only the last dimension can be adjusted using Redim Preserve.

Comment: Oh VBA. VBA. Why. Thanks @ScottCraner, that hurts my soul.

Comment: @JNevill  You mentioned Collections earlier.  I was using arrays as I could populate the array in the same positioning as I would for and excel range. X columns and Y rows.  When I look at collections, as far as I understand them, they are a 1 dimensional array essentially.  Is it possible to have a two dimenisional collection that you can imsply add and remove from?

Comment: I don't believe so. Collection is more of a key/value pair type of object. Much like an array, but instead of an index, you can define a key that returns the value for that key. Another option for you might be to dimension your array to the size of the range, load everything (putting blanks at positions where the conditions don't hit), and then shrink your array to size after you've made all the decisions (which will require more coding, but will get the job done). Kind of a two pass approach.